# How do I download the JAI for GeoServer?

Tags: gis, geoserver, jai

Per creating an optimized geoserver build on my Linux(Ubuntu) server, I've tried to install JAI as an addition to my JRE.
Unfortunately, JAI seems to have disappeared from the Java website!

The JAI link seems to not be functional: http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/
Same with JAI IO tools: https://jai-imageio.dev.java.net/binary-builds.html#Release_builds

Same with all those others on the documentation, and the other places I've found online.

Any word on the status of JAI? or any way to download JAI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is stated on [JAVA considerations](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/java.html#installing-native-jai-on-linux) you can find them on [OpenGEO](http://data.opengeo.org/suite/jai/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) API page on oracle.com, JAI and the associated Image I/O tools are now community source projects on java.net.

https://java.net/projects/jai appears to be the page for the JAI project on java.net.

Comment: the last modification in the SVN trunk of the core was 8 years ago

Answer (score 0):

Ciao,
the speed up you can get by installing binary JAI is usually small or at least small enough to not bother with the installation.

In any case, you can get the binaries from here:
https://java.net/projects/jai-core/sources/svn/show/trunk/src/share/mediaLib?rev=111

Match the binary with the OS of choice.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the JAI-Ext effort https://github.com/geosolutions-it/jai-ext/wiki that GeoServer's primary developers are spearheading - "an internal effort to replace Oracle JAI operations which are basically unsupported at the time of writing."

Comment: this is sadly not (yet) a plug and play option as JAI supposedly was. However, it seems to be alive and kicking (last modified 3 months ago)